# fromJSON in R Shiny

Tags: r, json, shiny

I made a shiny application. In this application, my data comes from JSON query but it works in local but it does not work in shinyapps.io.

Please, please and please help me...

My query:

```
    ispark_refresh <-reactive({

fromJSON("https://api.ibb.gov.tr/ispark/Park",flatten = T)


    })
```

My Log:

[image]

Comment: It seems that your connection to the server times out after 10 seconds of not answering.
Are you sure that your instance has connection to the internet?

Also, do you require "fresh" data (does it update), or can you serve it locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mhh already pointed out, the problem seems to be in how the request is handled on your side. You can use `httr` to set a timeout in seconds and a maximum number of retries to shield your dashboard from missing data:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

res <- RETRY(
    "GET",
    url = "https://api.ibb.gov.tr/ispark/Park",
    timeout(30),
    times = 5
)

res <- fromJSON(content(res, as = "text"))
```

**edit**: I also checked in shinyapps settings pane and it seems that you can't set connection timeouts from there. The only allowed options are for setting worker and user timeouts. I am not quite sure if there's someplace else I should look at.